# How to record friend call on Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

I have installed Asterisk on Ubuntu

sip.conf

```
[10000001]
type=friend
host=dynamic
qualify=yes
secret=pw_random
context=demo

[10000002]
type=friend
host=dynamic
qualify=yes
secret=pw_random
context=demo

...
```

extensions.conf

```
[demo]

exten => _1XXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten => _1XXXXXXX,2,Set(CALLFILENAME=${EXTEN:1})
exten => _1XXXXXXX,3,Monitor(wav,${CALLFILENAME},m)
```

However, Asterisk runs Dial and gets stuck, the users can talk each other on call, but Asterisk doesn't record the audio

run `asterisk -rvvv`, I get

```
-- Executing [10000001@demo:1] Dial("SIP/10000002-00000045", "SIP/10000001") in new stack
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Called SIP/10000001
-- SIP/10000001-00000046 is ringing
-- SIP/10000001-00000046 answered SIP/10000002-00000045
-- Channel SIP/10000002-00000045 joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <1b882cee-b0f0-473f-aafb-651169788159>
-- Channel SIP/10000001-00000046 joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <1b882cee-b0f0-473f-aafb-651169788159>
```

Any idea? Thanks!!

---

Update:

If I modify extensions.conf to

```
exten => _1XXXXXXX,1,Set(CALLFILENAME=${EXTEN})
exten => _1XXXXXXX,2,Monitor(wav,${CALLFILENAME},m)
exten => _1XXXXXXX,3,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
```

log is

```
-- Executing [10000001@demo:1] Set("SIP/10000002-00000000", "CALLFILENAME=10000001") in new stack
[Apr 14 00:56:50] WARNING[8649][C-00000000]: pbx.c:4910 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'Monitor' for extension (demo, 10000001, 2)
== Spawn extension (demo, 10000001, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/10000002-00000000'
```

error `pbx_extension_helper: No application 'Monitor' for extension` is weird.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it.

It's due to `pbx_extension_helper: No application 'Monitor' for extension`

Application 'Monitor' is not found because asterisk doesn't load `res_monitor` module according to [this link](http://www.asterisk.name/modules.conf.html)

So, I add `load=res_monitor.so` in `/etc/asterisk/modules.conf`

The file looks like

```
[modules]
autoload=yes
load=pbx_config.so
load=chan_sip.so
load=chan_iax2.so
load=res_rtp_asterisk.so
load=app_hangup.so
load=app_dial.so
load=app_stack.so
load=res_monitor.so
load=pbx_functions.so
load=codec_ulaw.so
load=codec_gsm.so
load=bridge_simple.so
```

Thank Shu Zhang!

Answer (score 1):

this is an old but i had the same problem, the way you solved it its correct, but you are just loading ALL MODULES... instead of making an slim module load.

```
[modules]
autoload=yes <---- THIS
load=pbx_config.so <---- DISABLED THIS
load=chan_sip.so
load=chan_iax2.so
```

So in order to make it work in a slim module load configuracion you must load

```
[modules]
autoload=no <---- THIS to NO

...

load=func_periodic_hook.so <---- THIS IS NEEDED IN ORDER TO LOAD MONITOR
load=load=res_monitor.so.so

...
```

Obviouly you need codecs and formats, here is a good slim config.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-slimming/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the directory /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/, /var/spool/asterisk/monitor, or you can find your ubuntu files by your file name. Since the verbose didn't show any warning I believe you are doing this right but the recorded file is hiding somewhere. You can fix the file name .

```
exten => _1XXXXXXX,3,Monitor(wav,fixedfilename)
```

And find this file name in linux.

Moreover you can take a look of this

[a link]http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Record

Comment: Yes I posted it wrong, but glad you found out the answer of your problem.